# How can I stop a running timer that runs in a while loop?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have an application where a portion of the code runs in a loop with a timer delay.

At the start of the application I declare:

```
public static CancellationTokenSource tokenSource1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
public static bool Timer1Running;
```

Here’s the looping area:

```
 while (App.runCardTimer && App.TimerSeconds > 0)
 {
   App.Timer1Running = true;    
   …
   await Task.Delay(1000, App.tokenSource1.Token);
   App.TimerSeconds--;       
   App.Timer1Running = false;    
 }
```

My application responds to a click on the screen like this:

```
wordGrid.GestureRecognizers.Add(       
   new TapGestureRecognizer()      
   {          
      Command = new Command(() =>          
      {          
         App.TimerSeconds = 0;          
         if (App.tokenSource1 != null && App.Timer1Running)          
         {              
            App.tokenSource1.Cancel();          
         }       
      })    
   });
```

When it runs and when the screen is clicked it gets to the code 
`App.tokenSource1.Cancel()`

However it then seems to stop.

Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong. I had expected the code to immediately go to the line `App.TimerSeconds--;` and didn’t expect it to just come to a stop before then.

Comment: But you have set App.TimerSeconds = 0, so surely the while now no longer runs, since it is dependent on App.TimerSeconds > 0?

Comment: `await Task.Delay` throws TaskCanceledException on cancel

Comment: If you want a timer, use a timer. If you [check the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5896), you'll see that `Task.Delay` itself uses a timer to set the completion status of a TaskCompletionSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await Task.Delay(1000, App.tokenSource1.Token);` 
throws `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException` when canceled. 
So you need to wrap it in try-catch:

```
{
   App.Timer1Running = true;    
   …
   try
   {
      await Task.Delay(1000, App.tokenSource1.Token);
   }
   catch(TaskCanceledException ex){}
   App.TimerSeconds--;       
   App.Timer1Running = false;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you. By the way.  Once I created a new tokenSource1 can I use it again and again?

Comment: You can use it to get tokens multiple times and consume them in many operations. But once CancellationTokenSource gets cancelled, all the tokens you get from it will cancel too and CancellationTokenSource itself transits into cancelled state permanently.